# Find Data Attribute and Info for Sibling Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a blog post and I am attempting to add a Next Post and Previous Post feature. I am using JS to do this.

I pull in data from an HTML page that list all of the blog post with HTML like this:

```
<div class="post-info" data-blog-post-ID="472140">
 <span class="link">/blog/post4</span> <!-- URL OF BLOG POST -->
 <span class="title">Post  4</span> <!-- TITLE OF BLOG POST -->
</div>
```

Once I pull in the data I want to run a function that will compare the blog ID of the current post then find that in the data. Once I do that I want to find the previous and next sibling to the div containing the blog ID and insert this into the page using `.html`.

I tried to get this to work but it doesn't. There are no errors so I believe my JS is incorrectly selecting the element?

Here is what I tried:

```
$(function() {
    var blogID = "{tag_blogpostid}",
        blogList = $(".blog-post-list").find("[data-blog-post-ID='" + blogID + "']");

    if (blogID == blogList){
        var prevLink = $(blogList).prev( ".link" ).text(),
            prevTitle = $(blogList).prev( ".title" ).text(),
            nextLink = $(blogList).next( ".link" ).text(),
            nextTitle = $(blogList).next( ".title" ).text();

        $( ".prev" ).html( '<a href="' + prevLink + '">' +prevTitle+ '</a>' );
        $( ".next" ).html( '<a href="' + nextLink + '">' +nextTitle+ '</a>' );
    }
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/kJQdF/) with additional HTML and the above code.

What is the problem and how do I fix the problem so I can create what I am attempting to achieve.

Comment: blogList is a jQuery object so why do you keep wrapping it with `$(blogList)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let us look at the code:

```
var blogID = "{tag_blogpostid}",
    blogList = $(".blog-post-list").find("[data-blog-post-ID='" + blogID + "']");

if (blogID == blogList){
```

So what are you comparing?

```
blogID    <-- String
blogList  <-- jQuery object
```

A string will never equal a jQuery object.

You should just check the length

```
if (blogList.length) {
    ...
}
```

And `blogList` is a jQuery object so there is no need to keep wrapping it in `$()`. `blogList.find(...)` will work just fine.

and finally the prev is wrong, it is looking for a sibling that has the class link. The link class is a child of that sibling.

```
prevLink = blogList.prev(".post-info").find( ".link" ).text()
```

of course you need to do it to the others.

---

```
$(function() {
    var blogID = "472140",
        blogList = $(".blog-post-list").find("[data-blog-post-ID='" + blogID + "']");

    if (blogList.length){
        var prev = blogList.prev(".post-info"),
            next =  blogList.next(".post-info"),
            prevLink = prev.find( ".link" ).text(),
            prevTitle = prev.find( ".title" ).text(),
            nextLink = next.find( ".link" ).text(),
            nextTitle = next.find( ".title" ).text();

        $( ".prev" ).html( '<a href="' + prevLink + '">' +prevTitle+ '</a>' );
        $( ".next" ).html( '<a href="' + nextLink + '">' +nextTitle+ '</a>' );
    }
});
```

Fiddle with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/3XjUx/

Comment: Thank you for schooling me on the finer details of JavaScript efficiency... I've learned a few things from your similar yet obviously superior solution to this problem! I keep editing my own solution just to keep up with yours! I must back out of this race!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlaw/kJQdF/2/)

```
$(function() {
  var blogID = "472140",
      blogList = $(".blog-post-list").find("[data-blog-post-ID='" + blogID + "']");
  if (blogList.length){ 
    var prevLink = blogList.prev().find(".link" ).text(),
        prevTitle = blogList.prev().find( ".title" ).text(),
        nextLink = blogList.next().find( ".link" ).text(),
        nextTitle = blogList.next().find( ".title" ).text();

    $( ".prev" ).html( '<a href="' + prevLink + '">' +prevTitle+ '</a>' );
    $( ".next" ).html( '<a href="' + nextLink + '">' +nextTitle+ '</a>' );
  }
});
```

As epascarello said, bloglist is a jQuery object, so there is no need to continue to wrap it in `$()`. Also, I changed the iteration for previous and next to be a little bit more straightforward since blogList captures a div, but you can change that however you want, just be aware of what blogList represents.

**EDIT** Once again, epascarello beat me to it... but it is much cleaner to just check the length on the blogList to ensure you found a div.